# Why can you take nav links out of the navbar container, and re-flow in HTML navbar/header tag? Will that cause layout/performance issues?

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown, nav

Suppose I have a `Navbar` wrapped by `header` tag with links on it, I structured it this way

```
    <header id="header" class="header active">

    <nav class="nav">
        <!-- NAV LOGO -->
        <div class="nav__logo">
            <a href="">
                <img src="./img/logo.svg" alt="" class="nav__img">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- NAVLINKS -->
        <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="" class="nav__link">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="" class="nav__link">About</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="" class="nav__link">Courses</a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="" class="nav__link">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <!-- ACTIONS -->
        <div class="nav__actions">

            <button>
                <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
            </button>

            <button>
                <i class='bx bx-cart' ></i>                
            </button>

            <button>
                <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
            </button>
        </div>

    </nav>
</header>
```

And on my `CSS`,

```
header{
    background: white;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

}

.header .active{
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav__logo{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav__list{
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    gap: 2.25rem;
}

.nav__link{

}

.nav__actions{
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.25rem;
    padding: 0px 1rem;
}
```

---

My questions are quite simple, yet I would like to confirm them somehow.
[image]

If I set my media queries and change my `CSS` `nav__list` - if it hits (max-width: 420px) to become a side menu by taking it out of the flow by `.nav__list: position:fixed`, will that cause problems and can be seen in dev tools? Like overlapping, layouts/performance, Is this the right way? Just take out certain elements even if they are under one root layout (header>nav - **nav_list**)?

Or do I need to create a new dedicated (menu list) for the sidebar menu?

---

P.S: I come from `Android` background, `XML` layouting is different, they are structured in a way by not taking certain elements out of the tag/flow.

Comment: It might depend on how you are structuring the main content area (i.e. below the header nav), but I've done it both ways: by changing `position` property or by toggling visibility between two HTML elements. Overlapping should be preventable by CSS styles around them. Performance _might potentially_ be a concern if the `position` toggle causes massive layout shift and significant page repaint, but I'd say it's fine as CSS is arguably by far the most effective way to handle layout in browser anyways.

Comment: Keeping _one_ HTML block and using CSS to change positioning makes it a simpler markup but may require you a bit of CSS acrobatics. Duplicating into _two_ HTML blocks and simply toggling visibility makes it simpler to build with no performance concern but it's less DRY and might require additional maintenance.